# pip install mysqlclient fails with "call to undeclared function" error

Tags: python, macos, mysql-connector-python, libmysqlclient

I am currently on macOS 14.3 on Apple silicon. I am trying to install mysqlclient using pip. I already have mysql package installed using `brew install mysql pkg-config` but my mysqlclient installation is failing due to the errors mentioned below:

I am trying to run `pip install mysqlclient`

I am getting the following error:

```
  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-14.1-arm64-cpython-311
      creating build/temp.macosx-14.1-arm64-cpython-311/src
      creating build/temp.macosx-14.1-arm64-cpython-311/src/MySQLdb
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql-client/include "-Dversion_info=(2, 2, 1, 'final', 0)" -D__version__=2.2.1 -I/Users/avishekde/.pyenv/versions/3.11.6/include/python3.11 -c src/MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-14.1-arm64-cpython-311/src/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql-client/8.3.0/include/mysql -std=c99
      src/MySQLdb/_mysql.c:527:9: error: call to undeclared function 'mysql_ssl_set'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
              mysql_ssl_set(&(self->connection), key, cert, ca, capath, cipher);
              ^
      src/MySQLdb/_mysql.c:527:9: note: did you mean 'mysql_close'?
      /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql-client/8.3.0/include/mysql/mysql.h:797:14: note: 'mysql_close' declared here
      void STDCALL mysql_close(MYSQL *sock);
                   ^
      src/MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1795:9: error: call to undeclared function 'mysql_kill'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
          r = mysql_kill(&(self->connection), pid);
              ^
      src/MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1795:9: note: did you mean 'mysql_ping'?
      /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql-client/8.3.0/include/mysql/mysql.h:525:13: note: 'mysql_ping' declared here
      int STDCALL mysql_ping(MYSQL *mysql);
                  ^
      src/MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2011:9: error: call to undeclared function 'mysql_shutdown'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
          r = mysql_shutdown(&(self->connection), SHUTDOWN_DEFAULT);
              ^
      3 errors generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mysqlclient, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

The following is the output from `pkg-config --cflags --libs mysqlclient`

```
-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql-client/8.3.0/include/mysql -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql-client/8.3.0/lib -lmysqlclient
```

Comment: And you read the installation steps in https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient?tab=readme-ov-file#macos-homebrew? Did you install pkg-config?

Comment: mysql_ssl_set() has been removed as of mysql 8.3.0 - for now you might want to brew install a specifically lower version of mysql until the client libraries catch up https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.3/en/news-8-3-0.html

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: Yes I have that installed. I have edited the question to reflect that. The issue is with mysql 8.3.0 as Ian mentions. The below answer fixes things for now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download the source code,and make some modifications, then build & install.
Here are the details:
https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient/issues/688

Answer (score 0):

If you're not ready to upgrade your mysqlclient library, you can also downgrade your version of Homebrew's mysql-client package and prevent Homebrew from upgrading it to 8.3.0.

Steps documented here: https://i-am-j.ag/blog/posts/python-mysql-8.3.0-homebrew/